# Group python objects by two fields in two-dimensional dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reference, grouping

I have a python class `Episode` that has two fields: `season` and `number`. I have a list ob `Episode` objects in `episode_list`. The list is ordered by season and then by episode. In the example below the data is created in this order.
What I want to do is this: I want to create a dictionary of `Season` objects. Each `Season` object also has a dictionary as a field called `episodes`. This dictionary is supposed to contain all `Episode`objects that have this seasons' number.
At the end of the minimal example below I print the grouped data and the result is:

S3E1
S3E2
S3E3
S3E1
S3E2
S3E3
S3E1
S3E2
S3E3

This it is wrong and (according to the data I created) should be:

S1E1
S1E2
S1E3
S2E1
S2E2
S2E3
S3E1
S3E2
S3E3

```
# required classes
class Episode:
    def __init__(self, season, number):
        self.season = season
        self.number = number


class Season:
    episodes = {}

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

# create episode data
episode_list = []
for i in range(3):
    episode_list.append(Episode(1, i+1))

for i in range(3):
    episode_list.append(Episode(2, i+1))

for i in range(3):
    episode_list.append(Episode(3, i+1))

# group episodes by seasons
seasons = {}
for episode in episode_list:
    for season_number in range(1, 4):
        season = Season(season_number)
        for episode in episode_list:
            if episode.season == season_number:
                season.episodes[episode.number] = episode
        seasons[season_number] = season

# print result
for sn, s in seasons.items():
    for en, e in s.episodes.items():
        print "S" + str(e.season) + "E" +  str(e.number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've made episodes a class attribute

```
class Season:
    episodes = {}

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
```

That means the same dict is being shared across all Season instances

You should make it an instance attribute

```
class Season:    
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.episodes = {}
        self.number = number
```

Comment: thank you so much, this absolutely solved my problem. as always in the end it was totally obvious. but after spending quite some time with this, I just didn't see it anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
class Season:
    episodes = {}
```

`episodes` is a class attribute. All `Season`s share the same `episodes` dict. You need to make `episodes` an instance attribute, like so:

```
def __init__(self, number):
    self.episodes = {}
    self.number = number
```

You got all the other attributes right, so it's kind of weird that this one is a class attribute instead of an instance attribute.

Also, note that looping over a dictionary:

```
for sn, s in seasons.items():
    for en, e in s.episodes.items():
```

isn't guaranteed to give any particular order. You could end up with Season 2 coming before Season 1. If it matters, you could loop in sorted order with `sorted`:

```
for sn, s in sorted(seasons.items()):
    for en, e in sorted(s.episodes.items()):
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Also your last comment is very useful and I can definitely use it to make sure I get the correct order. Thanks so much!